Dji Mini 3 pro animation
I have a question.
I downloaded a free 3d model of DJI Mini 3 Pro and I wanted to spin the wings... but I don't know why I can't. I'm still on early beginer level and in this case I have some lines (maybe bones) connected with the drone.
Can someone tell me how can I spin only motors and wings or what can be wrong with this file?
Cheers!

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

The lines are most likely indicating that the wings are parented to the drone. But hard to tell anything when you do not show any screenshots of the scene, the object, the outliner etc. or maybe even share the file.

@GordonBrinkmann
I downloaded a file from here:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/dji-mini-3-pro-274f2ad2731e42b793b784c9f8453677

Sorry but we can't look at models linked from external sites where you have to log in to download.

@JohnEason ahh... sorry my bad. So here is the link for wetransfer:
https://we.tl/t-8DZbthSsBx

Unfortunately that model isn't designed to be animated. The dotted lines you can see are relationship lines linking the part to an Empty. The "wings" (more correctly called "fan blades") are actually parented to their own individual Emptys. If you try to rotate one of those it will just rotate the blade on its own and intersect the one next to it rather than rotating the whole assembly with both blades and the motor..

@JohnEason ohhh i got it. Well... I've couldn't understand why this getting so crazy sometimes, when I try to roatete it. At least thank you for your time and that you tried to help.
